# HTML form data not posting to Web API Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I've read 100 articles and tried everything, but I cannot seem to get my form data (on an aspx page) to post to my Web API controller.
Here is my ridiculously simple HTML:

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="/api/WebApi/TestPost">
    <input type="text" id="someinput" name="someinput" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Me" id="mysubmit" />
</form>
```

Here is my ridiculously simple controller code:

```
public class WebApiController : ApiController
{

    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
    public string SomeOtherPost()
    {
        //This one ALWAYS gets hit
        return "1";
    }


    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
    public string TestPost(string someinput)
    {
        //This one NEVER gets hit
        return "2";
    }
}
```

The action with no parameters always gets hit, the action with the string parameter never gets hit.

This seems like it should be super easy.  What on earth am I missing?

Comment: MVC does not support overloads like that.

Comment: That's good to know, thanks.  But even when I give the first action a different name, the same problem occurs.  I'll update my post to name the first action 'SomeOtherPost()'

Comment: As far as I know action methods declaration should return an ActionResult object or an object which class is a child of ActionResult like JsonResult for instance. Have you tried that?

Comment: @capote1789, I changed both actions to return a new JsonResult(), but it did not make a difference.  The SomeOtherPost() function still gets called, even though my form is specifically posting to TestPost().  I'm starting to think this has something to do with routing?  Thanks

Comment: That's what I'm thinking too, take a look at this article [Routing in ASP.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api) is a really useful for api routing setup. Hope it helps.